# getting value from the html tag and save in python dictionary with string type

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Want to extract the tag and save the value **"AAAAA"** with **pp-0,pp-1,pp-2,pp-3,pp-4 etc...** and it corresponding value **1000, 1002, 1003, 1004 etc...** in **python dictionary format**, which **[d]** should be the **first level and "AAAAA"** should be the **second level start with [d] key and "AAAAA@X##"** plus save all dictionary data in **string** format.

**Coding**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span id="AAAAA" style="display:none">
<span id="pp-0" style="display:none">1000</span>
<span id="pp-1" style="display:none">1001</span>
<span id="pp-2" style="display:none">1002</span>
<span id="pp-3" style="display:none">1003</span>
<span id="pp-4" style="display:none">1004</span>
<span id="pp-5" style="display:none">1005</span>
<span id="pp-6" style="display:none">1006</span>
<span id="pp-7" style="display:none">1007</span>
<span id="pp-8" style="display:none">1008</span>
<span id="pp-9" style="display:none">1009</span>
<span id="pp-10" style="display:none">1010</span>
<span id="pp-11" style="display:none">1011</span>
<span id="pp-12" style="display:none">1012</span>
<span id="pp-13" style="display:none">1013</span>
<span id="pp-14" style="display:none">1014</span>
<span id="pp-17" style="display:none">1015</span>
<span id="pp-27" style="display:none">1016</span>
</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all('span')
```

**Wrong Output**

```
[<span id="AAAAA" style="display:none">
<span id="pp-0" style="display:none">1000</span>
<span id="pp-1" style="display:none">1001</span>
<span id="pp-2" style="display:none">1002</span>
<span id="pp-3" style="display:none">1003</span>
<span id="pp-4" style="display:none">1004</span>
<span id="pp-5" style="display:none">1005</span>
<span id="pp-6" style="display:none">1006</span>
<span id="pp-7" style="display:none">1007</span>
<span id="pp-8" style="display:none">1008</span>
<span id="pp-9" style="display:none">1009</span>
<span id="pp-10" style="display:none">1010</span>
<span id="pp-11" style="display:none">1011</span>
<span id="pp-12" style="display:none">1012</span>
<span id="pp-13" style="display:none">1013</span>
<span id="pp-14" style="display:none">1014</span>
<span id="pp-17" style="display:none">1015</span>
<span id="pp-27" style="display:none">1016</span>.....]
```

**Expected Output** *(in coding level)*

```
{'d': 'AAAAA@X##{"pp-0": 1000, "pp-1":1001, "pp-2":1002, "pp-3": 1003, "pp-4": 1004, "pp-5": 1005, "pp-6": 1006, "pp-7": 1007, "pp-8": 1008, "pp-9": 1009, "pp-10": 1010, "pp-11": 1011, "pp-12": 1012, "pp-13": 1013, "pp-14": 1014, "pp-17": 1015, "pp-27": 1016}'}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{'d':'AAAAA@X##{"pp-0": 1000, "pp-1":1001, "pp-2":1002, "pp-3": 1003, 
"pp-4": 1004, "pp-5": 1005, "pp-6": 1006, "pp-7": 1007, "pp-8": 1008, 
"pp-9": 1009, "pp-10": 1010, "pp-11": 1011, "pp-12": 1012, "pp-13": 1013, 
"pp-14": 1014, "pp-17": 1015, "pp-27": 1016}'}
```

Comment: dear, d is key of that dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created separate dictionary for to add data and finding data-text and id according to html

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
span=soup.find_all("span")

x={}
other_dict={}

x['d']=span[0].get("id")
for i in span[1:]:
    other_dict[i.get("id")]=i.get_text()
```

After getting 2 dictionary now we can convert other_dict to string using json module and concanting both the data final output can be achieved!

```
import json
data=json.dumps(other_dict)
final=x['d']+data
x['d']=final
print(x)
```